# ASP.net Charting control

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, charts

I want to create a radar chart to display in my asp.net website. To do this I am user the `ASP.net` charting controls `4.0`: `c#`

I can create radar chart with out issue however my problem occurs when I wish to make the `X-Axis` labels into a hyper link.

To make it easier for myself I created a little test. Really simple data with a bar chart. I had to create a custom labels to the `X-Axis` clickable. Worked just as I expected. However when I change the chart type `ChartType = SeriesChartType.Radar;` the `X-Axis` labels stop being links.

Here is the simple test code I am using:

```
ChartArea ca = new ChartArea();

List<string> f = new List<string>();
f.Add("Label 1");
f.Add("Label 2");
f.Add("Label 3");
f.Add("Label 4");

Series s = new Series();
s.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Radar;
s.Points.Add(new DataPoint(1, 20));
s.Points.Add(new DataPoint(2, 30));
s.Points.Add(new DataPoint(3, 40));
s.Points.Add(new DataPoint(4, 50));
Chart2.Series.Add(s);

for (int i = 1; i < s.Points.Count; i++)
{
    CustomLabel cl = new CustomLabel();
    cl.FromPosition = i-0.5;
    cl.ToPosition = i + 0.5;
    cl.Text = f[i];
    cl.Url = "someRandompage.aspx";
    ca.AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(cl);
}
Chart2.ChartAreas.Add(ca);
```

Any ideas on how to get this going?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to solve it by checking out RadarChart examples on following links.

[Example found right here!](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/24/new-asp-net-charting-control-lt-asp-chart-runat-quot-server-quot-gt.aspx)

[Source code right here!](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=1591)

Comment: There is some really good examples there and I have looked through them before but no luck. I think the solution to my problem is finding out the area on the created image that the custom label takes up so I can add this to the imagemap. The chart will be created dynamically so I cannot assume a location of the labels. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check for MapAreAttribute of chart [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020150803/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/102809-1.aspx) and [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/MSWinWebChart/thread/47a8fb5f-6b3e-4906-8909-30efcbbb5af3/).

Answer (score 0):

In the end I decided not to use asp.net charts. They just are not that great. Ended up using highcharts. They are a javascript charting tool that were able to do everything I wanted. They are supported across all the major browsers and they look nice. The asp.net charts control on the other hand are not very nice and slow to render.

There are a few other javascript charting tools available which seem nice. If at all possible I would recommend going with the javascript stuff.